# Problems in opening local .doc and .xls files in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am build an ionic app and I am almost done. Now I have a problem. whenever user clicks on attachments in my app.. there are .doc, .xls, .jpeg, .pdf files. I am getting the base64 code converting it and generating a local url. I can open Pdf and all image files but I have problems in opening .doc an d.xls files. Could anyone suggest me how to open them ..Thanks in advance :)